# Why is the grid turned on only on the last subplot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, widget

I am using subplots in a function which is using a slider widget inputs to calculate some stuff and plotting results.
I want to turn on the grid for all subplots of ax1. But somehow jupternotebooks only turns it on only on the last plot...

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.html.widgets import interact
%matplotlib inline

## Plot 
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(6,2)
plt.subplots_adjust(right = 2, top = 8 )
# Show the major grid lines with dark grey lines
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-')
# Show the minor grid lines with very faint and almost transparent grey lines
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#999999', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)

## Giergeschwindigkeit über v und ay
ax1[0,0].plot(v_ms, omega)
ax1[0,0].set_ylabel('Giergeschwindigkeit [rad/s]')
ax1[0,0].set_xlabel('Geschwindigkeit [m/s]')
ax1[0,0].set_title('Giergeschwindigkeit über Geschwindigkeit')
# ... more subplots
plt.show()
```

It looks like this:
[image]

And can you explain to me why in my case

```
ax1.grid()
```

throws an error?

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'grid'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because `plt` will only operate on the last-created axes object.
And the reason you're getting that error is that `ax1` is a numpy n-dimensional array, not an axes object.

You can do this to iterate over the numpy n-dimensional array to create the grids:

```
for row in axes: 
    for ax in row: 
        ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-')
        ax.minorticks_on()  
        ax.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#999999', linestyle='-',alpha=0.2)
```

Result (without `plt.subplots_adjust()`):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set grid for every ax object, so in your case you should set like this:

```
ax1[0,0].grid()
ax1[0,1].grid()
```